# Template not found with Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates

Developing a Django app and decided to ditch the Linode for Heroku. Just too much crap to deal with. So I can run my app fine using `python manage.py runserver` both locally and when ssh'd into the Linode, but when pushed to the heroku git repo (goes through, runs fine), I get `TemplateDoesNotExist at / home.html`. On my computer the folder is located at `Heroku/Django_App/OmniCloud_App/Templates/` (Django_App is the folder with settings.py, etc.).

Heroku is checking at `/app/OmniCloud_App/Templates/` How can I see the file structure of Heroku and specify that in settings.py so I can run the app locally for development as well as pushed to Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've pushed to heroku you may connect to an isolated instance of your heroku app through bash. You can access this with:

```
heroku run bash --app appname
```

(Keep in mind this does use hours off of your heroku credit though).